# Dynamic modification of snapping values

Tags: javascript, haskell-snap-framework, interact.js

I start with interract.js and try to figure out how to snap my elements to defined sizes in the index targets. It works well when I set the values statically but actually I would like to dynamize the values so that each element can snap to each other.
I didn't find how to do this in the doc, would you have a research track allowing me to make the values evolve according to the displacement of the blocks, so that they become "snappable" ?

ideally I think these values should be able to change dynamically each time you move an element, so using `dragend` event, but how do you make the change in values take effect...
thank you for your feedback.

```
// here I define my static values for the snap
var dynamicRestrictions = [
        {x: 200, range: 20},
        {x: 400, range: 20},
        {y: 300, range: 20}
    ];

interact('.resize-drag')
    .draggable({
        inertia: true,
        modifiers: [
            interact.modifiers.snap({
                targets: dynamicRestrictions, // <= how to dynamic edit them ?
                relativePoints: [
                    {x: 0, y: 0},
                    {x: 1, y: 1},
                    {x: 0, y: 1},
                    {x: 1, y: 0},
                ],
                offset: 'parent'
            }),
            ],
            autoScroll: true,
            listeners: {              
                move: dragMoveListener,
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a function on the `onstart` event.

```
.draggable({
    //...
    onstart: dragMoveStartListener,
    //...
})
```

which will allow you to set your hang values.

```
function dragMoveStartListener(event) {
    var element = $(event.target);
    dynamicRestrictions.length = 0;
    $('.resize-drag').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(element)) {
            var thisPosition = $(this).position(),
                snapX = thisPosition.left,
                snapY = thisPosition.top,
                snapWidth = $(this).width(),
                snapHeight = $(this).height(),
                range = 20;
            var sumWidth = parseInt(snapX + snapWidth),
                sumHeight = parseInt(snapY + snapHeight);
            dynamicRestrictions.push({x: snapX, y: snapY, range: 10});
            dynamicRestrictions.push({x: snapX, range: range});
            dynamicRestrictions.push({x: sumWidth, range: range});
            dynamicRestrictions.push({y: snapY, range: range});
            dynamicRestrictions.push({y: sumHeight, range: range});                      
        }
    });
}
```

I tested it and it works pretty well, except that I don't know how to snap both vertically and horizontally, each time it's one or the other...
looking for a little bit more, should do the job